# XDocument how can I comment an Element

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I just want to know how I can comment an entire element using XDocument.

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse("<configuration>
      <connectionString>
          ...
      </connectionString>
<configuration>");

/*Something like that*/ doc.Root.Element("connectionStrings").NodeType = XComment; /*??*/
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Something like this, perhaps:

```
var element = doc.Root.Element("connectionStrings");
element.ReplaceWith(new XComment(element.ToString()));
```

Sample input/output:

Before:

```
<root>
  <foo>Should not be in a comment</foo>
  <connectionStrings>
    <nestedElement>Text</nestedElement>
  </connectionStrings>
  <bar>Also not in a comment</bar>
</root>
```

After:

```
<root>
  <foo>Should not be in a comment</foo>
  <!--<connectionStrings>
  <nestedElement>Text</nestedElement>
</connectionStrings>-->
  <bar>Also not in a comment</bar>
</root>
```

Add line breaks if you want to...

Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: Curse you, Skeet! I was writing the same thing, but then you came along and wrote it quicker and better. Haha, +1!

Comment: I want all the child node to bein comment Replace all?

Comment: @Cedric: They already are - it's all within the comment part. (If you list all the descendant elements in the above, it *won't* show `nestedElement`.)

Answer (score 0):

And if anyone wants to know how to do multiline:

```
public static  class Extensions
{
    internal static void AddMultilineComment(this XDocument xDoc, string[] lines)
    {
        var builder = new List<string> { Environment.NewLine };
        builder.AddRange(lines);
        builder.Add(Environment.NewLine);
        xDoc.Add(new XComment(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, builder)));
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TryIt()
{
    var xDoc = new XDocument();
    xDoc.AddMultilineComment(
        new string[]
        {
            "This excellent post answered my original ",
            "question, so then it seemed like a handy",
            "thing to write a multiline extension!",
        });
    xDoc.Add(
        new XElement("connectionString",
            new XAttribute("uri", $"{new Uri("https://www.ivsoftware.com")}")));
}
```

Result:

[image: Resulting Xml construct]